# Best exterior paint for a guardrail by the ocean?

Tags: paint

I noticed the top of the guardrails over looking a dock have begun to peel. Mostly on top and only a few spots. I plan to refinish top and bottom rails and the balusters.  Orbital sand all surfaces with 60 and 100 grit and feather the loose paint. My only concern is that the wood may be Teak which I believe has a high oil content? Is there a special primer to use? Or is a special paint (oil) needed? How do I keep the salt water from damaging the paint?

Comment: Don't really care why this was closed, but it shouldn't be for whom ever thought it was soliciting a brand or company. No where is a product endorsement in the question. Get a grip whomever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would sand the rail down until all traces of your latex and primer are gone. Now prime it with oil based **Kilz primer** then apply oil based **Rustoleum** onto that. These are both commonly available in Canada, I'm not sure about US (or wherever you may live.)